# How to make this function to be continuous

Tags: functions

problem in an assignment given by our lecturers.

$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^3 , x <0 \\ 
2x , x=0 \\ 
\sin x,x>0
\end{cases}
$

a) Find the values of $x$ for function, $f(x)$ is continuous.

b) Evaluate $f'(0)$, if exists. If the derivative does not exist, explain why.

Our current concern is there might be some typo in the question, or the question is unsolvable.

[Updates - 1]
We're having trouble answering question no.(b), how can we know if $f'(0)$ exist or not? What approach can we start at?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: I think at X =0 the value of the function should be given $2k$

Comment: @DigAmma why? what is k?

Comment: @Nkzlxs I added the function definition in Latex. Please add the remaining text and remove the picture. Also tell us your thoughts, why do you think where is a typo or the question is unsolvable?

Comment: Hello, i added MathJax expression just now for easy viewing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I is simple for $x\ne 0$. If $x>0$  the derivative $f'$ exists and if $x<0$ the derivative $f'$ exists.

At $x=0$ the function $f$ is continuous: The function $f(x)$ does not only coincide with the function $\sin(x)$ for $x\lt0$ but it does coincide with $\sin(x)$ even for $x\le 0$. The function $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $0$ so $\sin(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ from the right side and so $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ from the right side. In a symbolic notation:
$$\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\sin(x)=\sin(\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}x)=\sin(0)=0$$.

$$\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}x^3(x)=(\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}x)^3=0^3=0$$. 
$f(x)$ is continuous from the left side, because $x^3$ is, too.

A similar argument holds for the differential quotient:

$$\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{\sin(h)-\sin(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin(h)-\sin(0)}{h}=\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$$

$$\lim_{h \uparrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \uparrow 0}\frac{h^3-0^3}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{h^3-0^3}{h}=(h^3)'(0)=3\cdot0^2=0$$

So both $$\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$ and $$\lim_{h \uparrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$ exist, but they are different, so $f'$ does not exist at $x=0$.

Note:

The following function definition define the same function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, because for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the value $f(x)$ is the same. For $x=0$ we have $$2\cdot 0 = 0 = \sin(0) = 0^3$$ and for $x\ne 0$ we have the same formula.

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^3 , x <0 \\ 
2x , x=0 \\ 
\sin x,x>0
\end{cases}$$

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^3 , x <0 \\ 
0 , x=0 \\ 
\sin x,x>0
\end{cases}$$

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^3 , x \le0 \\ 
\sin x,x>0
\end{cases}$$

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-x^3 , x \lt 0 \\ 
\sin x,x \ge0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 0):

1. $f$ is continuous in $0 \iff f(0)=\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)= \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)  \iff f(0)=0.$
2. We assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Hence $f(0)=0.$ For $x>0$ we have $ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0^+.$ And for  $x<0$ we have $ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= -x^2 \to 0$ as $x \to 0^-.$

Conclusion ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying!